# Can't get annotation from class sent from server - Java

Tags: java

I'm loading class files from my server to use as Plugins, I'm wanting to use an Annotation to identify the main class but its not reading any and just returning null...

EDIT: Yes in my annotation class I have @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

```
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    SSLSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = (SSLSocket) PacketHandler.socketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 8331);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeByte(11);
        out.writeInt(sessionId.getBytes().length);
        out.writeBytes(sessionId);
        out.writeInt(scriptId);
        while (in.readByte() == 1) {
            byte[] nameBytes = new byte[in.readInt()];
            in.readFully(nameBytes, 0, nameBytes.length);
            String fileName = new String(nameBytes);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[in.readInt()];
            in.readFully(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
            System.out.println("File name: " + fileName + " file bytes: " + fileBytes.length);
            String name = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 6);
            Class<?> c = defineClass(name, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
            System.out.println(c.getAnnotations().length);
            System.out.println(c.getAnnotation(ScriptManifest.class));
        }
```

Output:

> File name: Ingredient.class file bytes: 1132
>
> 0
>
> null

My Annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ScriptManifest {
    public String name();
}
```

Comment: Is your `ScriptManifest` annotation meta-annotated with `@Retention(RUNTIME)`?

Comment: Hey, yeah it is. I updated my post showing my manifest

Comment: Do you transfer @ScriptManifest too? Could it be possible that annotation is discarded if it's missing in classpath? Can you check?  :)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? I can't reproduce the problem. Make sure you have the annotation on the class-path of your server too.

Comment: So the plugins are built with the library of the program what the server is sending to. The annotations aren't sent from the server as the Annotation is in the application of what the plugins are built off. Could this be because the Annotation object is in a different classloader and not defined in my custom classloader?

Comment: Yeah seems like i was right, I wasn't setting the parent as the SystemClassLoader... Silly me!

Comment: @JoeTaylor That was going to my next guess :) Glad you could figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the parent of my custom ClassLoader to the SystemClasssLoader seemed to have solved my problem!